# Groovy shell script doesn't recognize export command

Tags: bash, macos, groovy, groovyshell

I'm running a groovy shell script where I'm trying to set the proxy before running the `aws` command:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.url.com:8099
aws s3 ls
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "export": error=2, No such file or directory
    at com.capitalone.cep.lensOps.run(lensOps.groovy:13)
```

The `export` command works fine when I run it in bash so what should I do in groovy to get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

`export` is a shell feature and not an external program. To run a program with a certain value in its environment, you can instead use `env`.

```
env http_proxy=http://proxy.url.com:8099 aws s3 ls
```